# Calling different Node js APIs from React Front End

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

**Greetings,**

I have a project based on Nodejs (Typescript) as Backend and React with Express in the Frontend.
In Backend, I have 3 docker containers (1-Postgres, 2-ServiceA, 3-ServiceB) with each assigned to different Port.

Then the 3 Containers/services are up and running using (`docker-compose build & docker-compose up`) and after that I run (`npm run start:dev`) on each folders of ServiceA and Service B.

My problem is how to use Express React to call functions from ServiceA api, then on another browser page call functions from ServiceB api.

**Help Please.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I understand your question, I suggest you to use an api gateway, like krakend (https://www.krakend.io/) i.e.

An api gateway aggregate your multiple backend (that now works on different port), under one single port (basically like a proxy) that you'll use to be listened by express.